# pthread_join does not work and mutex dont work in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I got two questions that are similar due to the fact that the code is almost the same. I am a newbie at using threads but I am not new to the idea and concept, but I cannot get this to work...

The task, create two threads (plus main) one that prints hello moon three times with short delay and one that prints hello world with long delay three times, one after another.

First version of the code got the issue that main sometimes quit before the threads have done its thing even though I use joins. This is the code:

Update: using pthread_join(&....); is not a good idea. I should have used pthread_join(...); (without &) this part seem to work as it should now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "wrapper.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


void *HelloMoon (void * arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    struct timeval stop, start;
    int i = 0;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        while(i < 3){
            gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
            if((stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)>=20000){
                printf("Hello Moon!\n");
                gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
                i++;
            }
        }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}


void *printHelloWorld(void* arg){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    struct timeval stop, start;

    int i = 0;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    while(i < 3){
        gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
        if((stop.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)>=1){
            printf("Hello world!\n");
            gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
            i++;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return(NULL);

}



int main(int ac, char * argv)
{

    pthread_t thread_id1, thread_id2;

    pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, HelloMoon, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, printHelloWorld, NULL);

    pthread_join(&thread_id2, NULL);
    pthread_join(&thread_id1, NULL);


    return(0);
}
```

This second code uses a while loop in main to make the behavior repeat forever. This "solve" the issue of main quitting but sometimes one thread run twice, making it print 6 times instead of three. Why is that? Code:

Update: I think this is because the loop create two new threads each time it is run, making the total number of threads greater than two and this in turn, having multiple threads with the same id results in this funny behavior. Am I correct or not?

```
int main(int ac, char * argv)
{

    pthread_t thread_id1, thread_id2;

    while(1==1){
        pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, HelloMoon, NULL);
        pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, printHelloWorld, NULL);

        pthread_join(&thread_id2, NULL);
        pthread_join(&thread_id1, NULL);
    }


    return(0);
}
```

Last questions, what is the best way of making threads run one after another forever? Is the while loop a good idea? Are the variables "i" the same for the threads? I think not but one source said it was so I want to be sure.

Comment: One, enable all compiler warnings - you should see something.  Two, you're not checking any return values.  Those are related here...

Comment: "*making the total number of threads greater than two and this in turn,*" no, as the calls to `pthread_join()` take care that both threads created during the iteration are gone, before the next iteration starts.

Comment: What is in `wrapper.h`?

Comment: wrapper.h is empty for now and is not used

Comment: @AndrewHenle return values from mutex lock or threads?

Comment: It's a good habit to check the return values of any function you use that can signal an error that way.

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_join` expects the thread id instead of a pointer to it as first parameter.

```
pthread_join(&thread_id2, NULL);
pthread_join(&thread_id1, NULL);
```

should be

```
pthread_join(thread_id2, NULL);
pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);
```